# When should I not set @OutputCache Shared Attribute in Webforms?

Tags: asp.net-4.0, webforms, outputcache

Reading the [@OutputCache documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) I have noticed the `Shared` attribute

Doc says:

> Shared
>
> ```
> A Boolean value that determines whether user control output can be
> ```
>
> shared with multiple pages. The
>   default is false. For more
>   information, see the Remarks section.

Remarks says:

> If you set the Shared attribute to
>   true, cached user control output can
>   be accessed by multiple Web Forms
>   pages. If you do not set it to true,
>   the default behavior is to cache one
>   version of user control output for
>   each page that contains that user
>   control. You can potentially save a
>   significant amount of memory by
>   enabling the Shared attribute. For
>   more information, see Caching Portions
>   of an ASP.NET Page.

So I'm starting to believe that normally this should be set to true for controls that are gonna be rendered exactly in different pages in order to save cache memory.

The question is... when should I **not** set `Shared` to true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use it when the control output is different across different pages.

Say you have a control whose output changes depending on how one navigates your site (breadcrumb control) - you do *not* want that to be shared across pages.